# Printing a object 2d array not printing the content

Tags: java, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

Here is my class that prints the 2D Array. My problem is instead of printing the content, it is printing the Object name. I want to then check to see what value is held in `content["hey"]`.

```
public class HelloWorld {

    private final static Object[][] content= {
        { "hey", "1234" },
        { "there", "5678" },                                       
    };

    public static Object[][] getContents() {
        return content;
    }

     public static void main(String []args){     
         System.out.println(getContents()[0].toString());
     }
}
```

Why is the name being printed instead of the content? How do I print the content?

Comment: You can use ArrayUtils.toString(Object); if youre cool with using the commons library.

Comment: @imtheman This is wrong.

Comment: You could use `Arrays.asList(getContents()[0])` since the returned list has a readable `toString`.

Comment: @khelwood how can I retrieve "hey" or "1234"

Comment: If you have a key value relationship of your data, you should not use a double array, but rather use a Map.

Comment: @nmore why a map over a array?

Comment: @fscore Because of your statement "I want to then check to see what value is held in content["hey"]". If you store your data in a map, you can do map.get("hey") and it will return 1234. The relationship between your data is more than just two strings in a list.

Comment: -1 for ignoring all comments and replies. A multidimensional array needs multiple indices; if you don't know that you need go back to basics.

Comment: when did I ignore comments and replies? I believe stack overflow is a good place to ask specific questions and get responses accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To print the "content of hey" (ie. '1234') change the `System.out` line in `main()` to the following:

```
System.out.println(getContents()[0][1].toString());
```

In your original code you are missing the call to the second dimension of your Object array.  Your call to `getContents()[0]` returns the reference to the Object `{ "hey", "1234" }` which is what is being printed.